# How to handle timeout for Uploading a blob in Azure Storage using Python SDK?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, python-3.9

I am trying to upload a blob to Azure Storage using Python SDK but I am unable to manage the timeout. The behavior of all timeout values are same.

SDK Version: azure-storage-blob==12.13.1

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, ContentSettings
from datetime import datetime


STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = ''
container = ''
blobFileName = ''
contentType = ''


def upload_blob(localFilePath):
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING)
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container, blob=blobFileName)
    content_setting = ContentSettings(content_type=contentType)
    with open(localFilePath, "rb") as data:
        blob_client.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True, content_settings=content_setting, timeout=30)


@retry(Exception, tries=5, delay=1)
def uploadImageToAzure(imagePath):
    try:
        upload_blob(imagePath)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f'Exception: {ex}, Type:{type(ex)}, Time:{datetime.now()}')
        raise Exception(ex)

    print('Successfully Uploaded the File')
    return True

uploadImageToAzure(imagePath)
```

To check the behavior of timeout. I just turn off my internet during uploading the blob.

Test Cases:
I just pick the random values of timeout and saw the behaviour of the above code

- timeout=1

```
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe5d848e9a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 09:25:42.543262
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe5d83c30a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 09:27:04.949785
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe5d83da940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 09:28:28.508035
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe5d837a340>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 09:29:58.473318
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe5d8393be0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 09:31:19.184696
```

- timeout=2

```
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f19f0164940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 09:46:25.328502
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f19f009b0a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 09:47:50.919091
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f19f00b2940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 09:49:14.144449
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f19f0056340>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 09:50:43.947462
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f19f006ebe0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 09:52:05.272197
```

- timeout=4

```
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2a08699910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 09:57:27.401257
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2a085d41f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 09:58:55.699520
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2a085ea910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 10:00:18.315710
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2a096ce310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 10:01:37.800908
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2a096e6bb0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 10:03:02.293558
```

- timeout=16

```
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff8c83d7880>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 10:19:15.195291
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff8c830f130>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 10:20:47.769388
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff8c8323880>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 10:22:14.996163
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff8c82c8280>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 10:23:37.736138
Exception: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff8c82ddb20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Type:<class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>, Time:2023-03-28 10:25:00.846901
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/_shared/constants.py) for the azure-storage-blob Python SDK, I can see the *Connection timeout* is **20** seconds and the *Read timeout* is **60** seconds.

Since your question is about the upload_blob which should be the client request timeout. I think this one defaults to the 20-second DEFAULT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
unless you pass a different value to timeout specifically while calling the upload_blob function.

*Note that this timeout parameter is expressed in seconds. This method may make multiple calls to the Azure service and the timeout will apply to each call individually.* More Info [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/4bc0a7a582a09e193e29cd028bbcde23a33b3cd8/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/_blob_client.py#L693). Hope this helps.